# What form tag do when I want to work with ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, post

This is my Html code:

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function logiin()
        {
            name_sent = document.getElementById('username').value;
            pass_sent = document.getElementById('pass').value;
            $.post(
                'login.php',
                {
                    name: name_sent
                },
                function show(data) {alert (data); }
            );
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!--<form>-->
        Username: <input type="username" name="username" id="username"> <br>
        Pass: <input type="password" name ="pass" id="pass"> <br>
        <input type="submit" onclick="logiin();">
    <!--</form>-->
</body>
```

It works with ajax and JQuery and works very well, too! :) But if i add form tag it doesn't work! why.?

Comment: Its not a good practice to call handlers inline. Yes that will work too but using form tags will ensures you don't run into problems.

Comment: @Jai - Why do you say it's not a good practice? In some cases, I'd rather see handlers inline rather than scattered all over JavaScript code where I have to hunt them down via the debugger.

Comment: @JustinNiessner I just said it because he is using jquery and jquery provides robust way doing some ajax calls, like click, submit etc.

Comment: @Jai: I use jQuery too but recently I started adding `onclick` attributes again. It makes it very clear which elements have events attached to them and which don't, and what they do when clicked. Separating the JS is wonderful and all but it can be much harder to trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because, when contained in a form, the submit button will try to submit the form.

The easiest way to prevent that from happening is to add `return false;` to the onclick handler:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="logiin(); return false;" />
```

The better way, though, would be to add the handler to the form itself (in case the user submits the form another way):

```
<form onsubmit="logiin(); return false;">
    <!-- Form elements here -->
</form>
```

Comment: Or you can make your `logiin()` function return false, and then use `onclick="return logiin();"`

Comment: @AlexW - That would work too. Without being sure if the OP is using the function anywhere else, I didn't want to change it.

Comment: Also, if you make an error in the function, it won't return false and your form will submit making it harder to find the error because the page will reload before you get to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable submit. If there is no button with type as submit, the form won't be submitted, unless you do it in your JavaScript code explicitly.

```
<body>
    <form>
        Username: <input type="username" name="username" id="username"> <br>
        Pass: <input type="password" name ="pass" id="pass"> <br>
        <input type="button" onclick="logiin();">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably because you are using an input button of type **submit**. Try using input of type **button**.

```
<input type="button" onclick="logiin();">
```

A button of type **submit** will automatically try to submit the form using post. See [w3c Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) for more information.

Comment: Not understanding the downvote here. Would the person please clarify why?